# DocumentSpecNames?

Tags: biztalk

I have been searching for over an hour and I give up. On the **XML disassembler component**, there is a `DocumentSpecNames` property. I can find no helpful documentation about what to put there. Is it like target namespace? What is it? An example would be helpful to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`DocumentSpecNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.biztalk.component.xmldasmcomp.documentspecnames%28v=bts.10%29) are used to validate messages against a specific schema ([`SchemaList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.biztalk.component.utilities.schemalist%28v=bts.10%29)). This is useful if you want to ensure strict messaging acceptance prior to processing a given message in your pipeline. See [related blog post](http://bergdaniel.se/validating-data-types-in-a-biztalk-receive-location).

The property value should be the name of the assembly and class name (*from above link*).

> DBLOG.ValidateMessage.IntegerSchema, DBLOG.ValidateMessage, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=349a4171d9432c58

Comment: Thank you. That blog was very helpful. Especially the aprt about how to find the assembly and name on the schema properties in biz talk manager. Nice!

Comment: The Xml Disassembler reads the document spec name from the message context.  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xmlnorm.documentspecname(v=bts.10).aspx)  It also has a DocumentSpecNames property on the pipeline component itself.  But what is in the message context? and what puts it there?

Comment: Jeremy: biztalk creates the message context from information about the message. It's automatic with the xml disassembler pipeline. You probably want message type. That will be the root node's xml namespace and the root node name with a '#' symbol between them

Answer (score 1):

Document namespace is a combination of "name", "assembly"

Step-1.
To find this you need to go to BizTalk Admin console then navigate to the application where you have deployed your schema Dll.

Step-2. Double click on the schema for which you want the Document Spec Name; you will find "General" tab on the left hand side of the window.

Step-3. On this General tab, "Name", "Assembly" and "Type" would be defined, now to get the Document Spec Name- Copy the "Name" and paste it to a notepad followed by a comma and a space.

Ex. Name- "Microsoft.EAI.SAP.Schema.PurchaseOrder"
    Assembly- "Microsoft.EAI.SAP.Schema, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=078b35dbd180a45k"

So as i defined above, Document Spec Name will be-

Document Name- "Microsoft.EAI.SAP.Schema.PurchaseOrder, Microsoft.EAI.SAP.Schema, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=078b35dbd180a45k"

Hope this will clear your doubt :)

Regards
Mayank