# A message sent to adapter "FILE" is suspended. Error details: Exception of type 'Microsoft.BizTalk.Message.Interop.BTSException' was thrown

Tags: biztalk

When I add an ESB Remove Namespace component to one of my send-ports I get the following error.

> A message sent to adapter "FILE" on send port "SendPort_301_AX" with
>   URI
>   "C:\Development\BizTalk\BelspeedQueue---\OUT\%SourceFileName%%MessageID%.xml"
>   is suspended.
>
> Error details: Exception of type
>   'Microsoft.BizTalk.Message.Interop.BTSException' was thrown.
>
> MessageId:  {88668BEC-51DF-4BC4-8F08-4CF09EBAEC3A}
>   InstanceID: {FA3E047D-917A-4B9B-B54C-78D7272027F5}

The error is a bit, non saying to me and google pops up with mainly 2-way ports or SQL type ports while this is a simple Fileport. Not using the remove namespace component creates a valid xml.

Below are the settings on the pipeline.

[image: SendPort pipeline components]

Comment: Why don't you just remove the targetNamespace form the AX Schema?  Then you won't need the Remove Namespace component at all.

Comment: Can you show more of the DocumentSpecNames bit that is of the edge of the dialog box (you can still black out the sensetive bits)

Comment: @Johns-305 It is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383792/this-assembler-cannot-retrieve-a-document-specification-using-this-type-with-a-c which is also related to an earlier question where it did not have a namespace.  He added one to try and make it more unique, but I think I've just worked out that the issue is that his DocumentSpecName is incomplete